# Electron forge macOS app for x64 and arm64

Tags: electron, electron-packager, electron-forge

From an arm64 mac machine - Im trying to package an Electron-forge app that will work both on an arm64 and x64 architectures.

I tried to use the @electron/universal npm package but couldt nake it run.
Their docs arent great.

From some reference i found
i added this to my package.json

```
"forge": {
   "packager": {
        "config": {
            "targetArch": "universal"
        }
      }
    }
```

runing "npm run package" outputs only an arm64 version.

any suggestions?